# How to view fetch list in apache nutch 2.3

Tags: apache, web-crawler, generator, nutch

I am using apache nutch 2.3 for crawling along with hbase and hadoop. I know that first injector job starts then generator job and then fetcher and so on.

I want to view fetcher list that is generated by generaorjob so some information and process on then before fetching starts?

Answer (score 0):

I think the new Wicket-based UI that was introduced in Nutch 2.3 could help here. There is not much documentation, but you can get it running like this:

```
bin/nutch nutchserver -port 8000 &
bin/nutch webapp -port 9000 &
```

Comment: Dear there is one problem, that It does not show running instances of crawler started through terminal. It works on those instances only that are started by webapp only. Any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible through web app. But you can manually view them in hbase itself. :)